# Issues parsing async functions with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, async-await

I'm trying to get webpack to parse a javascript file that is using the new async/await syntax, but it keeps giving me a parsing error.

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    foo: './foo.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'webpack-compiled.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "async-func-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "foo.js",
  "scripts": {
    "buildWithBabel": "babel foo.js --out-file babel-compiled.js",
    "buildWithWebpack": "webpack --progress --colors"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-async-functions": "^6.13.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}
```

My babel.rc file:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-async-functions"
  ]
}
```

And the foo.js file:

```
async function asyncFunc() {
  return 123
}

asyncFunc().then(x => console.log(x))
```

If I run the npm script 'buildWithBabel', it runs fine with no errors and creates the babel-compiled.js with the proper output.

However if I run the npm script 'buildWithWebpack', I get the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR in ./foo.js
> Module parse failed: C:\Users\Redark\Desktop\asyncFuncTest\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!C:\Users\Redark\Desktop\asyncFuncTest\foo.js Unexpected token (1:6)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:6)
> ```

I don't need to transform the async functions, just parse it. I'm not sure why it's not working for webpack as it should using the "syntax-async-functions" plugin in the .babelrc right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`transform-regenerator` plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-regenerator/) as well, `syntax-async-functions` only allows Babel to parse the input (and then leave it alone). Webpack doesn't understand ES8 syntax yet, that's why it fails without having them transpiled.